# How to get a value from a dictionary key?

Tags: python

I'm using two lines of code from an API doc, which spits out the image below. The only information I want is the "close" value (112).  How do I get this?

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

    print(response.text)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Raa.png)

From research it looks like it's spitting out a dictionary? However, I've tried the following code but it's spitting back and error:

```
for values in response
        print(values, "Key balue", response[values])

#error
  File "hub.py", line 17
    for values in response
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need a colon.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are missing a colon at the end of the for-loop. Try this:

```py
for values in response:
        print(values, "Key value", response[values])
```

Alternatively, you could try using the enumerate function like this:

```py
for key, value in enumerate(response):
    print(key, "Key value", value)
```

Comment: That is called a colon, not a semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks, got that error taken care of! Now its saying: "AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'values'"....Any ideas? :/

Comment: I've added another method using the enumerate function, Try using that. I have no idea why your code would give an attribute error though.

Comment: @BhavyeMathur `values` is not an attribute of a `Response` object in Python `requests`. Having looked at the question in some more detail it looks like he wants to parse a JSON response so needs to start by loading it as JSON. (I added a separate answer about this.)

Comment: @alani Ahh, that would make sense. I was thinking of `requests` as a simple Python Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> response = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
>>> type(response)
<type 'dict'>

>>>
>>> for item in response:
...  print item
...
1
2
3
>>> for item in response.values():
...  print item
...
one
two
three
>>>
>>> for item in response.keys():
...  print item
...
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the syntax error! but another one popped up: "AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'values'".... any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a JSON response, and need to parse it as JSON. The `requests` module makes this easy with `response.json()`

It is hard to see exactly what the response consists of because you have shown it as an image which loses some of the text, rather than pasting as text into the question. But it looks like you want something like this:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
for key, value in response.json()["quote"].items():
        print(key, value)
```

By the way, you can write the first line more simply using the `get` method.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```